# Hash regex for malware recognition

Tags: hash, md5

I'm looking to store two types of hashes for recognizing blacklisted code. These are the FireEye "import hash" (or [imphash](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2014/01/tracking-malware-import-hashing.html)) and the ssdeep ["fuzzy hash"](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/). Is there a regex (or formal documentation) I can use for type-checking these hashes?

The examples I've seen of an imphash look like MD5, but I haven't found a formal commitment to 32 hex characters. Similarly, I've seen a few examples of a fuzzy hash, but no commitment to a particular length, character set, or format.

Thanks....
(Cross-posted to [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29734/hash-regex-for-malware-recognition))

Comment: Please do not cross-post on StackExchange sites

Comment: I'm also not sure this question is on-topic on either site

Comment: What it looks like you are asking is simply about the specification of the 2 hash types you mention, and then to use those specs to design a regex. If you get the specs, you can ask the question over at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The examples I've seen of an imphash look like MD5, but I haven't found a formal commitment to 32 hex characters.

The first hit I get when googling for imphash is https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2014/01/tracking-malware-import-hashing.html which clearly states:

> ...Generating the MD5 hash of the ordered list

ssdeep hashes are completely different when looking at http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/usage.html